# Convert form input to uppercase or replace

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I have a list of people predetermined. My form has an initial input. If the user puts `j`, for example, I'd like to be able to post this as `J` so that the response would be upper-case.

OR:

When the response `j` or `J` is entered, within responses the document would rewrite that to `John`. I think this would be more difficult as you'd have to account for all occurrences of the letter `j` for example.

My PHP is currently `$text = "<a href='{$url}'>{$title}</a> Submitted By: {$name} on: {$timestamp} <br><br> \n";`

The input for the form is;

```html
<input type="text" placeholder= "Initial:" name="name" required style="width: 3.5em;" maxlength="1" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
<input type="submit"><br>
<style>#name-name:valid { text-transform: uppercase; }</style>
```

I'd just like to either.

A) Force upper-case on input, but the CSS isn't working?
B) `$_POST' the initial as upper-case.

How would I do whichever makes the most sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the changing the case when submitting the form why not change the case when you are displaying the name by doing something like `{ucwords($name)}`

Comment: I'm needing to change it when submitting because after that the name is just stored as the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in javascript as they type:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder= "Initial:" name="name" required style="width: 3.5em;" maxlength="1" onKeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
```

and then do it serverside, using [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

```
$text = "<a href='{$url}'>{$title}</a> Submitted By: ".strtoupper($name)." on: {$timestamp} <br><br> \n";
```

`$name` is a little confusing if you mean initial, so you might want [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

Also you should not forget about stored XSS attacks. So when you output from user input make sure you use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$text = '<a href="'.htmlentities($url).'">'.htmlentities($title).'</a> Submitted By: '.htmlentities(strtoupper($name)).' on: '.$timestamp.' <br><br>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing css **text-transform: uppercase;** on input You can convert text to uppercase

Comment: OP is already using the style you mentioned in your post. You should review OP's code and then help him/her understand why and where it went wrong.